# Fetch source field value

Tags: configuration, pdf

I have used a custom model where I am fetching value of `<source_field>` when I print an Invoice. Below is the code used in `config.xml`.

```
<pdf>
            <totals>
                <mymodule translate ="title">
                    <title>My Module Value</title>
                    <source_field>mymodule_amount</source_field>
                    <model>mymodule/sales_pdf_mymodule</model>
                    <font_size>7</font_size>
                    <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                    <sort_order>650</sort_order>
                </mymodule>
            </totals>
        </pdf>
```

I have created a Model file under `MyModule/Model/Sales/Pdf/Mymodule.php` and the DB filed name is `mymodule_amount`.

Below is my model file code

```
<?php

class Namespace_Mymodule_Model_Sales_Pdf_Mymodule extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default
{

    public function getTotalsForDisplay()
    {
        parent::getTotalsForDisplay();
        $mymoduleAmount =  $this->getMymoduleAmount();
        $label    =  'Some label';        
        $fontSize =  $this->getFontSize() ? $this->getFontSize() : 7;
        $total = array(
            'amount'    => '-'.$mymoduleAmount,
            'label'     => $label,
            'font_size' => $fontSize
        );
        return array($total);
    }

}
```

In the above code, `$this->getMymoduleAmount()`, returns null and can't fetch the value as defined in `<source_field>`.

Please Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the total from the source field you can simply call `getAmount` if your class extends `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default` which it appears to do.

```
/**
 * Get Total amount from source
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getAmount()
{
    return $this->getSource()->getDataUsingMethod($this->getSourceField());
}
```

Comment: How do I call getAmount in above code ? Where do I need to perform the changes ?

Comment: `$amount = $this->getOrder()->formatPriceTxt($this->getAmount());` should get you the formatted price amount. This is taken directly from the original `getTotalsForDisplay` code

Comment: why it does not work with my source field defined ? Or could you pls explain the code a bit

Comment: Because either you do not have a function `getMymoduleAmount` or it does not call the original function.

Comment: I agree that I don't have the getMymoduleAmount function. If necessary, where should I create it and how to fetch value from that function ? Moreover why can't I use the source_field value directly ?

Comment: I would replace your call to `getMymoduleAmount` with `$this->getOrder()->formatPriceTxt($this->getAmount())` or simply `$this->getAmount()`

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're suggesting. But can't get the source_field thing into head. Why it does not work ? and what if I remove the `<source_field>mymodule_amount</source_field>` form my config.xml ?

Comment: It does not work because in your code you are never calling it. The filed is used in the function `getAmount` which you never call in your custom code.